# Ubuntu 23.10 - Authentication Error - Login issue after suspend

Tags: login, suspend, 23.10

Recently I came across in my Ubuntu Desktop `v23.10`, my laptop screen goes to suspend mode after 5 mins of inactivity. When I woke up the laptop and entered the correct login credentials, it showed "Authentication Error" and the screen froze. I wasn't able to do anything from my keyboard and the only valid thing I could do was to shutdown my laptop manually by power button.

After turning on my laptop, it showed me a list of system level logs. After searching on StackOverflow I encountered a solution, where entering into TTY terminal and installing Ubuntu desktop using the `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` command would solve this issue.

Then I restarted my system using TTY terminal, and my Ubuntu becomes normal and shows my desktop screen. This issue happens whenever I tried to login after my system suspends. Even though my login credentials were correct, it showed an authentication error and I had to perform the same steps to get back my original desktop screen.

My system specs
Name: DELL G15 5511
Processor: Intel i7 11th Gen
GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3050
GNOME version: 45.2

[image: Authentication Error issue - Ubuntu 23.10]

Comment: After it suspends and resumes, are you able to go to TTY then do `loginctl` and `loginctl unlock-session c<NUMBER>` then switch back?